# Passing Array of Custom Object from Android To WCF: The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name

Tags: c#, android, wcf, soap

I'm trying to send an array of custom object type from android to WCF

I'm getting this error as a response from the WCF.

```
 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
 There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter 
 http://tempuri.org/:customers. The deserializer has no knowledge of any 
 type  that maps to this name.
```

The code that I've used is from the example listed in the accepted answer of this question [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619201/ksoap-cannot-serialize-exception-when-passing-user-defined-class-as-parameter-t)

Here is KvmSerializable user defined class for customers:

```
public class Customer implements KvmSerializable {
public int Customer_ID;
public String Customer_Name;
public String Customer_Family;

public Customer() {
}

public Customer(int customer_id,
            String customer_name, 
            String customer_family) {

Customer_ID = customer_id;
Customer_Name = customer_name;
Customer_Family = customer_family;
}

public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (arg0) {
case 0:
    return Customer_ID;
case 1:
    return Customer_Name;
case 2:
    return Customer_Family;


 }
 return null;
 }

 public int getPropertyCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 25;
 }

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (index) {
case 0:
    info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
    info.name = "Customer_ID";
    break;
case 1:
    info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    info.name = "Customer_Name";
    break;
case 2:
    info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    info.name = "Customer_Family";
    break;
default:
    break;

   }
  }

 public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (index) {
case 0:
    Customer_ID = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
    break;
case 1:
    Customer_Name = value.toString();
    break;
case 2:
    Customer_Family = value.toString();
    break;
default:
    break;
}

}

 }
```

And now c# user defined class for customers

```
 public class Customer
{
    public int Customer_ID;
    public string Customer_Name;
    public string Customer_Family;
}
```

Here is CallSoap class that I defined for send KvmSerializable object via this:

```
public class CallSoap {
public static String NAMESPACE = "http://127.0.0.1:80/";
public static String URL = "http://127.0.0.1:80/service.asmx?WSDL";
public static Customer[] customers;
public static int AddCustomer(Customer[] customers) {
String MethodName = "AddCustomer";
SoapObject soapAddRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, MethodName);
//customers Parameter
SoapObject soapDetails = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customers");
SoapObject soapDetail[] = new SoapObject[customers.length];

for (int i=0;i<customers.length;i++){
    soapDetail[i]= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Customer");
    soapDetail[i].addProperty("Customer_ID", customers[i].Customer_ID);
    soapDetail[i].addProperty("Customer_Name", customers[i].Customer_Name);
    soapDetail[i].addProperty("Customer_Family", 
 customers[i].Customer_Family);
    soapDetails.addSoapObject(soapDetail[i]);

}

soapAddRequest.addSoapObject(soapDetails);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( 
 SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapAddRequest);
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Customer", new Customer().getClass());
HttpTransportSE HttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try {
    HttpTransportSE.call(NAMESPACE + MethodName, envelope);
    String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
    return Integer.parseInt(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return 0;

    }
 }
```

and finally the AddCustomer method in server side:

```
[WebMethod]
public int AddCustomer(Customer[] customers)
{

for(int i=0;i<customers.Length;i++){
    //Access to customer fields for allrows via 
    int id = customers[i].Customer_ID;
    String name = customers[i].Customer_Name;
    String = customers[i].Customer_Family;
}
return customers.Length;

}
```

Comment: can you please post some code snippet to understand it in a better way?

Comment: I've added them, please have a look at the question again